# Website is in HTTPs but wordpress woocommerce throws error at checkout

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, ssl

On my website I have woocommerce and at the checkout page, it just keeps the refreshing icon over and over and over. My SSL is through Cloudflare.

Please go here https://evemirror.com/shop/?post_type=product&p=40
and get to the checkout page where you enter your payment method and you'll see it wont stop refreshing. When you check the console in google chrome this is what you get:

```
    ?page_id=6:16 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://evemirror.com/shop/?page_id=6' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://evemirror.com/shop/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.8.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
e @ ?page_id=6:16
jquery-migrate.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
jquery.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://evemirror.com/shop/?page_id=6' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://evemirror.com/shop/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
send @ jquery.js:4
jquery.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://evemirror.com/shop/?page_id=6' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://evemirror.com/shop/?wc-ajax=update_order_review'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: It's because the ajax request are do under "http" protocol instead of "https".

Comment: So, I went into the settings of wordpress and changed the site url and store url from http to https and that made the checkout work but now the wp-admin page or login wont load https://evemirror.com/shop/wp-login.php

Comment: You use a proxy Cloudfare to provide the SSL, try this: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/ssl-and-https/#websites-behind-load-balancers-or-reverse-proxies